Authenticate towards Joomla 4 from a pwa mobile app (vue3)
I wanted to get a view for a very basic implementation to my eyes.
A vue3.js pwa app with pinia state managment plays the role of 'frontend'
A joomla 4 website which will play the role of 'backend/headless'
As for some weird reason Joomla 4 webservices only support a single token for Super Admin,
how I can implement the very basic functionality:
a) A user to authenticate from Vue3.js app into joomla and get an access token
b) vue3.js get ack of the token store in pinia state and use it to any further call towards joomla
c) dismiss token on vue3.js app logout
is there something working for this please?
